# How to find which DOM element corresponds to precise scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to find the DOM element that corresponds to my horizontal scolling position. Passing a position of 25px should return the DOM element #2.

So far what I did is calculating the width of my elements to find the one that corresponds to the scrolling position but this is not a viable solution since in my real application my element's widths are not equal. Asking here if there is a more logical way of doing this.

[image: pass a position of 25px the DOM element 2 is returned]

I am using Vue js but it's not a requierement for the solution to my problem.

Comment: Element: getBoundingClientRect() method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect should give you the properties that you would like to consider

Comment: You could treat it as a type of collision detection problem: find the element that intersects the viewport that is also the leftmost. This will handle your variable widths of elements with ease.

Comment: I'll try those solutions, thanks!

Comment: You want [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)